# Can I create a powerpoint transition that REMOVES an element from the slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I'd like to create a powerpoint slide, and have elements dissappear from the slide, rather than appear.  Can I do that?  If so how?

If it matters, I'm using Powerpoint 2003.

(literally, I'm creating a slide that shows things pushing onto a stack, and then popping off...the popping off part requires a dissappear.)

Comment: Please note: There is no need for a not-superuser tag. This is a valid and relevant question and is very much in line with SU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I feel silly - found it as soon as I posted the question.

Click the element you'd like to dissappear, and in the "Custom Animation" frame, click "Add Effect" -> "Exit", select the type of "exit" transition you'd like to transition the element off the slide.

Answer (score 2):

Erm... there are many actions in powerpoint that allows an element to DISAPPEAR, FADE AWAY, FLY AWAY, ROTATE AWAY, etc. etc? Look under "Exit Effects".

Is that what you want? You might want to clarify your qn a wee bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd make a second slide, copy everything from the first slide, and delete the item off the stack. Then again, I'm old school like that.

The best part is, you can go back and forth between the pushed and popped states as many times as you want without having to replay your animations.